# Advantages of Setting priority_queue Container

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

With the stl `priority_queue` you can set the underlying container, such as a `vector`.  What are some of the advantages of specifying a container for the stl `priority_queue`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Setting the underlying container makes it possible to separate out two logically separate concerns:

1. How do you store the actual elements that make up the priority queue (the container), and
2. How do you organize those elements to efficiently implement a priority queue (the `priority_queue` adapter class).

As an example, the standard implementation of `vector` is not required to shrink itself down when its capacity is vastly greater than its actual size.  This means that if you have a priority queue backed by a `vector`, you might end up wasting memory if you enqueue a lot of elements and then dequeue all of them, since the `vector` will keep its old capacity.  If, on the other hand, you implement your own `shrinking_vector` class that does actually decrease its capacity when needed, you can get all the benefits of the `priority_queue` interface while having the storage be used more efficiently.

Another possible example - you might want to change the allocator being used so that the elements of the priority queue are allocated from a special pool of resources.  You can do this by just setting the container type of the `priority_queue` to be a `vector` with a custom allocator.

One more thought - suppose that you are storing a `priority_queue` of very large objects whose copy time is very great.  In that case, the fact that the `vector` dynamically resizes itself and copies its old elements (or at least, in a C++03 compiler) might be something you're not willing to pay for.  You could thus switch to some other type, perhaps a `deque`, that makes an effort not to copy elements when resizing and could realize some big performance wins.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

The `priority_queue` class is an example of the [adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).  It provides a way of providing the services of a priority queue over an existing data set.  As an adapter, it actually requires an underlying container.  By default, it specifies a `vector`. (from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/priority_queue/priority_queue/)).

In terms of the advantages, it's simply a more flexible.  The `priority_queue` uses the following methods of the backing store and requires it to support random access iterators.

- `front`
- `push_back`
- `pop_back`

By providing it as an adapter, you can control the performance characteristics by supplying a different implementation.

Two examples that implement this in STL are `vector` and `deque`.  These both have different performance characteristics.  For example, a `vector` typically is continguous in memory, whereas a `deque` typically isn't.  The `push_back` operation in a vector is only amortized constant time (it might have to reallocate the vector), whereas for the `deque` it's specified in constant time.